# Select the maximum value from a GROUP BY operation in CockroachDB?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, cockroachdb

After grouping rows, how do I also include the maximum value for the group in the return value?

For example, if I have this data:

```
INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, total) 
VALUES 
(1, 19.99), 
(2, 19.99), 
(1, 5.99), 
(2, 25.99);
```

I know that I can return each customer using this query:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM orders GROUP BY customer_id;
```

But how do I add the maximum value for `orders.total` to the returned values?

Comment: what's the point in posting such questions and answering them yourself?

Comment: StackOverflow encourages users to ask and answer their own questions, as it helps other users who might have similar questions in the future. See the FAQ here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: sure..but this question has been asked thousands of times and there is a tag `greatest-n-per-group` specifically.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting another relevant tag! CockroachDB is a new product, so people may not be familiar with its SQL dialect. I don't think adding a question and answer specific to CockroachDB hurts anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CockroachDB supports the standard SQL syntax for this kind of relationship. The following query produces one result for every `customer_id`, containing the `customer_id` and the maximum `total` for that customer:

```
SELECT x.customer_id, x.total
FROM orders AS x
JOIN (SELECT o.customer_id,
    MAX(total) AS max_total
    FROM orders o
    GROUP BY o.customer_id) y 
ON y.customer_id = x.customer_id
AND y.max_total = x.total
GROUP BY x.customer_id, x.total;
```

The result against the sample data is the following:

```
+-------------+-------+
| customer_id | total |
+-------------+-------+
|           1 | 19.99 |
|           2 | 25.99 |
+-------------+-------+
(2 rows)
```